# How to prove the determinant is $|A|^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, kronecker-product

$A=(a_{ij})$, and $I_m$ is the identity matrix of order $m$. How to prove the following?

$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}a_{11}I_m&a_{12}I_m&\cdots&a_{1n}I_m\\a_{21}I_m&a_{22}I_m&\cdots&a_{2n}I_m\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}I_m&a_{n2}I_m&\cdots&a_{nn}I_m\end{array}\right|=|A|^m$$

Comment: Please explain notation - a matrix within a matrix?

Comment: The notation is standard, @lux.

Comment: Repeated copies of a matrix used to form elements of a matrix would not be considered standard. Moreover, the op has not shown any attempt to provide context for the question, nor to show their efforts at forming a solution. This site is not a homework site

Comment: Block matrices are a thing @lux

Comment: Had it been written with the kronecker product I would have had no complaint

Answer (score 3):

Shuffle the rows and columns until the matrix looks like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & O & \dots & O\\
O & A & \dots & O\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & O\\
O & O & \dots & A\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and now it is clear.

Answer (score 3):

From the determinant of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product),

$$\det \left( \mathrm A \otimes \mathrm I_m \right) = \left( \det \left( \mathrm A \right) \right)^m \cdot \left( \det \left( \mathrm I_m \right) \right)^n = \left( \det \left( \mathrm A \right) \right)^m$$